# Windows Callgrind results browser, alternative to KCacheGrind

Tags: windows, valgrind, profiling, callgrind

Is there any tool, other than KCacheGrind, being able to view callgrind results? Preferably for Windows platform?

Comment: It is possible to use KCacheGrind on windows using KDE For windows (http://windows.kde.org/). There's a fair bit of bloat from the dependencies if you're installing it just for KCacheGrind though.

Comment: can anybody mention tools for mac platform ?

Comment: Do have a look at [Lailin Chen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4425999/993915) below

Comment: 1. Install WSL (Bash on Windows)
2. Install VcXsrv (newer version of XMing) and start the daemon.
3. In Bash on Windows: # apt-get install -y kcachegrind
4. Add line `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` to `~/.bashrc`.
(Re-source `.bashrc` or restart shell if necessary).
5. $ kcachegrind
6. Be anazed about the kcachegrind window opening on your Windows Desktop!

Comment: For those looking for setting up kcachegrind with WSL2: [How to set up working X11 forwarding on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2)

Comment: Now on windows 11 with wsl2 you can just launch X11 programs from the cli. No more need for XMing. It looks shitty though, maybe I'm missing some KDE packages but it's usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[alleyoop](http://alleyoop.sourceforge.net/) and [valkyrie (broken link)](https://#) are alternative front ends.

May have enough suport for what you want, you can use mingw to compile for Windows native if SUA does not work out of the box.

Comment: so nothing out there with pre-compiled binaries that works for windows?

Comment: kcachegrind from the kde-installer should be precompiled.

Comment: Do you know, how to use SUA? I use to use Cygwin for several years already (and it's awesome, but very slow) and I was also trying to find how to use SUA, but I wasn't very successful.

Comment: BTW I wonder why this answer is marked as accepted, since Valkyrie doesn't support CacheGrind profiles currently and the only information about Alleyoop and CacheGrind I was able to find was that it doesn't open it. Also neither of them have binaries for Windows.

Answer (score 107):

I have compiled kcachegrind on windows using QT4.7, here is the binary bundle (including the dot utility to generate call graph):
http://sourceforge.net/projects/precompiledbin/files/kcachegrind.zip/download

Comment: I've been using WinCacheCrind, but the call graph feature of kcachegrind is the killer feature. thanks so much for these binaries!

Comment: Thanks from me too, Lailin! Works great on Win 8.1 Pro!

Comment: There seems to have a port of the 0.7.4 version at https://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/files/0.7.4/

Comment: Anyone can help me ? I download and opened it on Win10 x64. After, I click Open... and go to folder with files like : cachegrind.out.7284 .. but the software DONT see this files in the folder, where is the problem ?

Comment: Here is a more recent build: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrind-windows-2020-build/postdownload

Answer (score 11):

Try WebGrind: https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind

Runs on your local PHP server. Be careful, use XDebug profiling with the XDEBUG_PROFILE flag or otherwise you'll risk overwriting your profiling output when you open WebGrind (Since WebGrind is also a PHP web application). The WebGrind website also details other approaches to work around this. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/).

Comment: wincachegrind does not have call graph

Answer (score 4):

It seems that WinCacheGrind cannot open output of callgrind. I have not tried opening output of cachegrind, but it should work, I guess.
From the Valkyrie page, (as of date) "Currently, Valkyrie supports Memcheck only, although work is in progress to handle Cachegrind and Massif."

Answer (score 1):

There's a new project called [XCallGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xcallgraph/) for viewing cachegrind files on Windows.

Comment: I've tested it now and it works like charm (WinXP). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried these:

- [QCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/)
- [KCachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/precompiledbin/)
- [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/)
- [XCallGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xcallgraph/)

They're very similar but differ in details. I can recommend the **QCacheGrind** which is the most feature packed and has also a graphical representation, which can help to identify problems much faster.