# PHP parser for cachegrind files?

Tags: php, windows, xdebug, kcachegrind

Is there such a thing?

I'm on windows and using the WinCacheGrind app and it doesn't seem to work with large files (~2 MB). I get errors like "cannot find call target".

Do you know any parser for such files written in PHP that can help me build my own cachegrind analyzer?

Comment: Personally, I would consider 2MB a bit small.. Some of mine exceed a hundred megs.. weird issue.

Comment: I had files over 1GB and it worked out, but now i have the same problem. I get "Cannot find call target" dunno why... some ideas?

Comment: [kcachegrind on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425999/6521116)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i am not sure if that is possible in PHP, but can try http://sourceforge.net/projects/precompiledbin/, if you just want to read cachegrind files, KCacheGrind actually works on linux but someone has ported it to run on windows

**Reference:** 
[Windows Callgrind results browser, alternative to KCacheGrind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425999/1237812)

Comment: tx, that app opens my files :D

Answer (score 5):

For a little while now, I've been using webGrind.

http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/

It's fantastic for debugging a server where you don't have easy/fast access to the files, as it is all read/interpreted remotely, then viewed online.

The platform independence has been great for me, as I develop on 3 computers and a laptop. As long as I can view a webpage where I'm working, I can debug my output. No need to install the same application across 4 separate computers, and eliminates the need to constantly transfer giant debugging files between said computers.

Nowadays I see it as a web application as necessary as something like phpMyAdmin.

I really hope this helps someone else trying to tackle a similar usage scenario.

EDIT: If you want to see it in action, WAMP comes with it (Mostly) preconfigured. [http://wamp.sourceforge.net/]

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, QCacheGrind (Windows-version of KCacheGrind) is much faster than WebGrind and very stable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/