# Wincachegrind gives an error

Tags: windows, profiling, cachegrind, wincache

When I tried to use `wincachegrind` and get the `cachegrind` file, it returns

> Cannot find call target.
>
> cachegrind.out line number:68

Anybody knows how to solve this?

UPDATE, here is the screen shot of the error:

[Click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VNPD.png)

Answer (score 8):

Probably you are using old version of WinCacheGrind. Make sure your version is the latest downloading it from the [official repository](https://github.com/ceefour/wincachegrind). Click on `Releases` and download the latest `wincachegrind-*.zip`.

Answer (score -1):

What size is your file? This SO question suggests it could be file size. [PHP parser for cachegrind files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026537/php-parser-for-cachegrind-files) The answers suggest alternatives to wincachegrind.

My files are about 1KB so that's not the answer. Oddly, there's not much resource for understanding(debugging) the error messages presented by wincachegrind.