# Running graphical Linux desktop applications from WSL 2 – "Error E233: cannot open display"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, xserver, xming

How can I run graphical Linux desktop applications from the command line of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

First, I installed WSL 2 following [these steps on how to install Linux on Windows with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10?redirectedfrom=MSDN) :

1. I installed Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Build 19619.
2. I installed the Ubuntu Linux distribution.
3. I changed the distribution version from WSL 1 to WSL 2.

Second, to enable graphical Linux desktop applications from the Bash shell of WSL, I followed [these steps on how to run graphical Linux desktop applications from Windows 10’s Bash shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/) :

4. I installed an X Server that is Xming.
5. As a test I installed the graphical GTK-based editor Vim :

   `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`
6. I set my display environment variable :

   `export DISPLAY=:0`
7. I tried to launch the application :

   `gvim`

   However, this did not launch the application. I got the following errors :

   ```
   E233: cannot open display
   Press ENTER or type command to continue
   E852: The child process failed to start the GUI
   Press ENTER or type command to continue
   ```

Any idea why this error is occurring?

Comment: Did you try to stop and restart your cli ?

Comment: Most answers here are from before this was a completed feature in WSL2. It not works quite well "out of the box": https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416242/4612476

Comment: Wouldn't this question work better on Super User?

Comment: Very valid question and many members seem to agree. Also very good answer with lots of upvotes. And yet, `closed` by an *experienced* member... that's why I try to avoid SO as much as possible...

Comment: @Raf It's what happens when they go to meta with a one sided account of what happened to get the mob going.

Comment: It's important to note here that "It is highly recommended to use the Microsoft Store version of WSL" and NOT to install via the command line. I could not get wsl GUI's to work until I reinstalled from the store rather than installing via wsl --install. github.com/microsoft/wslg

Answer (score 133):

The networking subsystem in WSL2 is different than the used in WSL1. You must [consider the differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#accessing-network-applications) to access networking apps running on Windows and on Linux:

- In WSL1, Linux uses the same IP addresses than the Windows host, then, you can access the applications using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
- In WSL2, Linux runs on a lightweight virtual machine and has a different IP address. To access networking apps running on the Windows Host you must use the Windows IP address.

### Checking the IP address of the Windows host

There are many ways to determine the IP addresses in the Windows host. You may run the following commands in your WSL Linux:

- `cat /etc/resolv.conf` shows the IP address of the `eth0` interface in Windows
- `ipconfig.exe` shows the all the IP configuration in the Windows host
- `route.exe print` shows the network routing configuration in the Windows host

### Setting the DISPLAY variable for WSL2

Based on the Microsoft documentation, you may set the DISPLAY variable checking the `nameserver` in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. ([@fqquiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775492/fquinner) and [@VPraharsha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12571294/vpraharsha) already mentioned this)

```
export DISPLAY=$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'):0.0
```

However, I had problems using this solution, probably because I use my notebook with a WiFi connection and multiple virtual networks. Instead of the previous solution, I determine the Windows IP address using `route.exe` and checking the interface used in the default gateway.

```
export DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0
```

### Setting the DISPLAY variable in the `.profile`

You may set the DISPLAY variable in your `~/.profile` file. I used the following code:

```
# set DISPLAY to use X terminal in WSL
# in WSL2 the localhost and network interfaces are not the same than windows
if grep -q WSL2 /proc/version; then
    # execute route.exe in the windows to determine its IP address
    DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0

else
    # In WSL1 the DISPLAY can be the localhost address
    if grep -q icrosoft /proc/version; then
        DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
    fi

fi
```

Comment: In addition, see @fquinner's answer. You must also open TCP port 6000 to your WSL's IP address. For example, if your WSL is on 172.23.80.1, add an inbound firewall rule to allow traffic from 172.23.80.0/12. See Instructions: https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using /etc/resolv.conf works for me, but route.exe does not. I don't know how to format this, but: Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.86.1    192.168.86.51     35
...
     172.22.224.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.22.224.1   5256     The 172 address is the correct one (at least it's the one that works).

Comment: If still doesn't work, check out my step by step answer on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4106#issuecomment-876470388

Comment: Thanks @KevinPatel for the instructions to configure the `vcxsrv` in windows 10. @KevinPatel and @shortpoet (in Github) are using the above solution to find the `DISPLAY` value.

Comment: using the `route.exe` method worked for me the classic `resolve.conf` method did not work

Comment: How are you guys running `route.exe` from Linux/WSL?? I get `run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for /mnt/c/Windows/system32/route.exe`

Comment: For some reason, running route.exe in my .zshrc file causes the entire terminal to hang iff it is opened in a Linux directory. I ended up needing to cd into a Windows directory before running route.exe:
`export DISPLAY=$(cd /mnt/c && route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0`

Comment: don't forget to restart the distribution "wsl --shutdown <distribution>"

Comment: I also had to cd into a Windows directory in order for the "route.exe" option to actually work.

Comment: `export DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0` worked for me

Comment: Tiny improvement on the route solution: `export DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | awk '/0.0.0.0/{print $4; exit}'):0.0` works nicely and only requires awk, no `grep` or `head`. Shaves a couple of milliseconds off startup time when you stick this into your `.profile`... ;]

Comment: Oh, man, Windows 10 - WSL 2...setting the second DISPLAY variable in your "Setting the DISPLAY variable for WSL2" section made it for me. THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: None of this works for me. I always get "Error: Can't open display:" followed by the DISPLAY variable. I am also unable to install vcxsrv.

Answer (score 40):

Had the same problem so I tried these other suggestions but what ended up working was allowing vcxsrv through the public firewall.  I know you're not using vcxsrv but perhaps it's the same problem for you too.

Install VcXsrv then enable public firewall like these pictures.  Open Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security using wf.msc at command prompt. Then allow connections like in these pictures.

[image: Double click then allow each of the public profiles for VcXsrv]

[[image: Allow the connection in VcXsrv firewall properties2]

Then run VcXsrv [from this guide](https://github.com/hubisan/emacs-wsl#run-emacs-in-graphical-display) for Windows 10 WSL2

Run VcXsrv by adding -ac addition parameter or type this at command prompt
"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -ac

Then type this into your WSL2 terminal

```
export DISPLAY_NUMBER="0.0"
export DISPLAY=$(grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'):$DISPLAY_NUMBER
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
# OPTIONAL Set the keyboard layout to US
setxkbmap -layout us
setsid emacs
exit
```

Comment: what is `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1`?

Comment: It is to use OpenGL in Windows instead of Linux. It doesn't work well because it only supports Open GL 1.4. I recommend do not enable it and install mesa-utils instead to do software rendering

Comment: for mer this works too : `export DISPLAY=$(hostname).local:0`

Answer (score 15):

*Updating my answer with more recent information than was available at the time the question was originally asked.  Keep in mind, though, that because this question is closed and off-topic here on Stack Overflow, eventually the answers here may become stale, since no new answers can be posted.  I recommend checking Super User or Ask Ubuntu for more on-topic and still-open questions on this topic.  It's always possible for a better answer to come along in the future.*

*Some existing questions for reference:*

- (Super User) [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1580610/1210833)
- (Ask Ubuntu) [Running GUI apps under WSL](https://askubuntu.com/q/1389908/1165986)
- (Ask Ubuntu) [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/1165986)

*With that in mind, the information below is currently mostly copied from my Super User answer to the question above.*

---

There are (at least) three options:

- With the release of WSL 1.0.0 (WSL via Microsoft Store application), both Windows 10 and Windows 11 users have full access to WSLg, which allows Linux GUI applications (X or Wayland) to run directly on WSL2 with no additional configuration.  Prior to 1.0.0, this feature was limited to Windows 11 users.

  Windows 10 users will need to be on a build ending in `.2311` or higher, which currently means installing [KB5020030](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2).  If the final four digits of your build number are lower than 2311, make sure your Windows is up-to-date, then find KB5020030 in the *Optional Updates*.

  Once on an up-to-date Windows 10 or Windows 11 system, either:

  Install WSL from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) or ...

  ```
  wsl --install
  # or, if already installed
  wsl --update
  # confirm 1.0.0 or later via:
  wsl --version
  ```
- A legacy alternative is the one that harrymc offers of installing a third-party X server.  I won't repeat the information on how to do so since it's already covered in that answer, although I will say that `export DISPLAY=$(hostname).local:0` will typically work, and is more concise.  This uses mDNS as I go into detail on in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933).
- Finally, if you want to run a Linux *desktop* under WSL, you might want to consider RDP.  You can install `xrdp` and just access a Linux desktop using Windows Remote Desktop connection.  See my steps for doing so in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986).  Note that only `xfce` is really necessary, although the answer includes more detail on running something more complex like Gnome Desktop.

Comment: This solution works for me. But a bit slower than the using VcXsrv in Windows.

Comment: It's important to note here that "It is highly recommended to use the Microsoft Store version of WSL" and NOT to install via the command line. I could not get wsl GUI's to work until I reinstalled from the store rather than installing via wsl --install. https://github.com/microsoft/wslg

Comment: @EdwardPescetto Interesting, `wsl --install` is supposed to use the Store to install, but "behind the scenes".  But I'll update the answer with that.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 9):

Adding to fquinner's answer,

Your **DISPLAY** env variable should be set as `export DISPLAY=X.X.X.X:0` to use the Windows host's IP address as WSL2 and the Windows host are not in the same network device, where X.X.X.X is the IP address

and your IP address is listed in **resolv.conf** against the nameserver (`$ cat /etc/resolv.conf`)

or simply `` export DISPLAY="`grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | sed 's/nameserver //'`:0" `` to load the correct IP address automatically. Additionally, you can add this to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` (If you use Zsh)

Comment: I have done this, and it doesn't return an error, but it stuck.

Answer (score 6):

There's a troubleshooting section here for debugging X11 on wsl2:

https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting

Port forwarding is not the same as WSL1 - your Linux services may be accessible via localhost for windows, but the reverse is no longer true.

So you need to use the internal IP of your windows host and tweak the firewall to allow the WSL network through.

Comment: How to tweak the firewall? I tried following the instructions at https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher/blob/master/README.md#user-content-firewall-rules but I don't get any pop-up from the firewall. It just hangs. DISPLAY looks reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4):

### [image]
The following instructions were copied and pasted from an article I wrote but it lost the original formatting, links, and screenshots:

**Source:** [How to Install Ubuntu Desktop with a Graphical User Interface in WSL2](https://thealtruist.medium.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-with-a-graphical-user-interface-gui-in-wsl2-5c188c0a261a)

---

Download VcXsrv:
Visit the official website
Click "Download"

---

Install VcXsrv:
Open "vcxsrv-64.1.20.8.1.installer.exe"
Click "Next"
Click "Install"
Click "Close"

---

Allow Access to VcXsrv:
Check "Private Networks"
Click "Allow Access"

---

Open PowerShell:
Press "⊞ Windows"
Enter "PowerShell" into the search bar
Right-click "Windows PowerShell"
Click "Run as Administrator"

---

Open WSL2:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`wsl`

---

Install Ubuntu Desktop:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt --yes install ubuntu-desktop`

---

Set the Username Variable:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`username=$(wslvar USERNAME)`

---

Create the Ubuntu Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`mkdir --parents /mnt/c/users/$username/.ubuntu/`

---

Open the Ubuntu Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`cd /mnt/c/users/$username/.ubuntu`

---

Download Linux Software Repository for Microsoft Products:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

**Ubuntu 20.04:**
`wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb --output-document packages-microsoft-prod.deb`
**Ubuntu 18.04:**
`wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb --output-document packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

---

Install Linux Software Repository for Microsoft Products:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo dpkg --install packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

---

Update the Repositories:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt update`

---

Install APT Transport for HTTPS:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt install --yes apt-transport-https`

---

Update the Repositories:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt update`

---

Install .Net:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt install --yes dotnet-sdk-5.0`

---

Add Arkane Systems to the Source List Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://wsl-translinux.arkane-systems.net/apt/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wsl-translinux.list'`

---

Update the Repositories:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt update`

---

Install Genie:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt install --yes systemd-genie`

---

Create the Sudoers File:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/genie" | sudo EDITOR="tee" visudo --file /etc/sudoers.d/$USER`

---

Create the Desktop Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# CREATE BASH SCRIPT

# Store block of text with here document
create_bash_script=$(cat << end_of_string

# Define necessary environment variables
export DISPLAY="\$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print \$2 }'):1.0"
export DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu"
export GDMSESSION="ubuntu"
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="ubuntu"
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="ubuntu:GNOME"
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE="x11"
export XDG_BACKEND="x11"
export XDG_SESSION_CLASS="user"
export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg"
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="\$HOME/xdg"
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="\$HOME/.config"
export XDG_DATA_HOME="\$HOME/.local/share" 
export XDG_CACHE_HOME="\$HOME/.cache"
export XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="\$HOME/Desktop"
export XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="\$HOME/Documents"
export XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="\$HOME/Downloads"
export XDG_MUSIC_DIR="\$HOME/Music"
export XDG_PICTURES_DIR="\$HOME/Pictures"
export XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="\$HOME/Public"
export XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="\$HOME/Templates"
export XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="\$HOME/Videos"

# Start desktop environment
gnome-session

end_of_string
)

# Store username environment variable in lowercase
username=$(wslvar USERNAME | awk '{ print tolower($0) }') &&

# Save block of text in bash file
echo "${create_bash_script}" > "/mnt/c/users/$username/.ubuntu/02_start_desktop.sh"
```

---

Download the Shortcut Images:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`wget https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/9fbc8a44-circle-of-friends-web.zip`

---

Unzip the Shortcut Images:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`unzip -o 9fbc8a44-circle-of-friends-web.zip`

---

Create the Shortcut Icon:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`convert -resize 64x64 ./circle-of-friends-web/png/cof_orange_hex.png ubuntu.ico`

---

Exit WSL2:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`exit`

---

Create the VcXsrv Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# RELOAD VCXSRV SCRIPT

# Store username environment variable in lowercase
$username = $env:username.tolower()  

# Store block of text with here-string
$reload_vcxsrv_script = @"

# Stop vcxsrv proccess that contains "1.0" in the program window title
get-process vcxsrv | where { `$_.mainwindowtitle -like "*1.0*" } | stop-process

# Start vcxsrv process in a large program window on display number one
start-process "c:\program files\vcxsrv\vcxsrv.exe" -argument ":1 -ac -nowgl -multimonitors -dpms"

"@

# Save block of text in powershell file
echo "${reload_vcxsrv_script}" > $env:userprofile/.ubuntu/reload_vcxsrv.ps1
```

---

Create the Ubuntu Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# CREATE VISUAL BASIC SCRIPT

# Store username environment variable in lowercase
$username = $env:username.tolower()           

# Store block of text with here-string
$create_vbs_script = @"

' Run PowerShell script in background
set application = createobject("shell.application")
application.shellexecute "powershell", "-file c:\users\admin\.ubuntu\01_reload_vcxsrv.ps1", "", "", 0

' Allow PowerShell script to complete
wscript.sleep 3000

' Run Bash script in background
set shell= createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "wsl sudo genie -c bash /mnt/c/users/admin/.ubuntu/02_start_desktop.sh", 0

"@

# Save block of text in bash file
echo "${create_vbs_script}" > $env:userprofile/.ubuntu/03_start_ubuntu.vbs
```

---

Create the Shortcut Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# Store block of text with here-string
$create_shortcut_script = @"

# Define location variables
`$shortcut_location = "`$env:userprofile\.ubuntu\Ubuntu.lnk"
`$program_location = "`$env:userprofile\.ubuntu\03_start_ubuntu.vbs"

# Create shortcut
`$object = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
`$shortcut = `$object.createshortcut(`$shortcut_location)
`$shortcut.targetpath = `$program_location
`$shortcut.iconlocation = "`$env:userprofile\.ubuntu\ubuntu.ico"
`$shortcut.save()

"@

# Save block of text in powershell file
echo $create_shortcut_script > $env:userprofile/.ubuntu/04_create_shortcut.ps1
```

---

Open the Ubuntu Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`cd c:\users\admin\.ubuntu`

---

Create the Shortcut:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`powershell.exe -file .\04_create_shortcut.ps1`

---

Open the Directory in Explorer:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`explorer .`

---

Launch the Ubuntu Desktop:
Double-click the "Ubuntu" shortcut

---

Open Terminal:
Click "Activities" in the top-left corner
Enter "Terminal" into the search bar
Click "Terminal"

---

Disable the Screen Lock:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into Terminal
Press "Enter"

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`

---

Install the Snap Store:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into Terminal
Press "Enter"

`sudo snap install snap-store`

---

Comment: All in 27 simple steps!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, but I get logged in to Ubuntu as root. Is that what you would expect? I followed the instructions above, except I always used my own username (in the instructions for creating the Visual Basic script, there are a two places where the "admin" user is used). Is there any way to get logged in under my own username instead of root?

Comment: @Entalpi Yeah, haha.

Comment: @John Try removing the sudo from the following line in 03_start_ubuntu.vbs: shell.run "wsl sudo genie -c bash /mnt/c/users/admin/.ubuntu/02_start_desktop.sh", 0

Comment: @TheAltruist Removing the sudo fixed it - I now get logged in under my own username. Thanks!

Comment: @John Awesome, glad you got it working!

Comment: @TheAltruist - After successfully using this for several months, I tried to set it up on another machine and can't get it to work. When I click on the shortcut to start Ubuntu, it brings up a window but it is completely blank. When I kill the window, VcXsrv gives me a message: "Exiting will close all screens running on this display. There are currently 0 clients connected".  If there are no clients connected, I assume something basic has gone wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @John - The firewall could be blocking connections to the display server. There have also been some changes to the process since this post. You can see the changes here: https://medium.com/p/71f4b78431a4

Comment: @TheAltruist - thanks, runs now with firewall rules updated. One other question - how do you copy and paste between windows and ubuntu?

Comment: Why should any of this be necessary? Ubuntu WSL is supposed to be fully functional and ship with an X server of its own.

Comment: @BobDoolittle, This process adds WSL support for Linux-based distributions with a graphical user interface. WSL only supports applications with a graphical user interface.

Comment: @david-littlefield I still don't get it. The only way Linux applications can display graphics is via Xlib which talks to the Linux X server. So it's all-or-nothing. Either Ubuntu WSL supports graphics, in which case all applications/desktops can use Xlib to display graphics, or it doesn't and no applications/desktops can display graphics. There is no "applications can display graphics but the distro can't".

Comment: @BobDoolittle This was written before WSL included X Server by default. At the time, there wasn't a one-stop tutorial that covered how to use WSL with a graphical user interface (GUI). So, it might not be necessary anymore, or maybe just the part about installing X Server, but I haven't tried it yet. Were you able to get the Ubuntu Desktop GUI to work without going through these steps?

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone didn't know, there is an easier way. In [2021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps), Microsoft gave us **WSLg**.

**Windows 11** and **Windows 10 22H2** *(build 19044.2311 or later)* include WSLg.
Drivers for vGPU *([Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29526) [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-wsl-support) [Nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl))* are [*recommended*](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#opengl-accelerated-rendering-in-wslg).

WSLg is [not compatible with WSL1](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#install-instructions-existing-wsl-install). New WSL2 instances will basically [*just work*™](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#install-instructions-fresh-install---no-prior-wsl-installation).
Older WSL2 systems [will need to be updated](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#install-instructions-existing-wsl-install) once:

1. In administrative PowerShell: `wsl --update`
2. `wsl --shutdown` to force a restart of the WSL

*Don't forget to remove any other modifications to `$DISPLAY` that you may have made!*

[image: Screenshot of WSLg running on Windows 11]

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't just work.

Comment: @EricHansen Sounds like you broke something else. I have now successfully done this on 3 different Windows machines (10 and 11). Did you check your version? Is something else setting display to something other than `:0`? I'm sure the WSL team would love to hear about your issues because they are trying to make this work well.

Comment: I'm on Windows 11 Pro 10.0.22000 Build 22000 and WSL version 2. It works today. It didn't yesterday. Did I restart in between? Yes. Did Windows do an update? I don't think so, but I must be wrong? Who knows. 

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez This absolutely works on Windows 10. Also, many people end up here trying to get WSLg working and then go down a long rabbit hole, like I did, that is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @CameronTacklind tell me which released not insider version of Windows 10 runs WSLg?

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Just match the requirements. If you want to use a non-insiders version, yes, go ahead, use the older ways.

Comment: @CameronTacklind Until you see a release version of Windows 10 with WSLg (and it won't happen) the older ways as you mention are not older at all. You cannot say that other methods are defunct because you are using a preview version of Windows. People will come to your answer thinking that their Windows 10 released on October 2021 will work and it won't. Put in the title (Insider version required)

Comment: @CameronTacklind The current release is listed on this official page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information, you are using a beta version intended for developers despite you want to call it "current". It only confuses users.

Comment: @CameronTacklind Hopefully you don't consider my latest edit "over-zealous."  I hope we can agree that *currently*, some disclaimer is needed that this only works on **beta/insider**, and Microsoft does *not* recommend Dev Channel for daily use.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Agreed on most all of this, but can you point me to the statement regarding there being no plan to release it for the next Windows 10/WSL update?  I hadn't seen a definitive statement either way, and I really expected/expect Windows 10 versions to continue to get WSL updates for a few more years.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds In my humble opinion, calling out such differences in versions of Windows is beyond the scope of this answer. Noting that the "Insider build of Windows 10" (or 11) was required seemed wholly sufficient to me. The way I had it also seems like the answer would stay true as the landscape evolved. I, also, personally, disagree that the other answers here are "good approaches". They certainly seem to work and are therefore worthwhile, but, imho, "good" is rather subjective, and I would not be happy with those solutions.

Comment: @CameronTacklind I feel it's *required* in order to be a responsible answer.  If you propose a solution that requires Insider Dev Channel on Windows 10, then it needs to cover the caveats.  Microsoft does *not* recommend Dev Channel builds for daily use.  The other answers *are* good (even the correct) approaches as of today for those not willing to run an unstable OS release.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds That feels like information that would belong in the comments, or as an asterisk. Not a block of text at the start of the answer that, imho, makes it less approachable.

Comment: @CameronTacklind https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/347 here is the statement. I was expecting to have these back ported to Windows 10 mainly because the CPU requirements of Windows 11. In fact any 20000 insider version is considered now exclusively part of Windows 11. Windows 10 stayed and will remain in 1904x sadly. They need to backport too many stuff begining with the new device driver architecture, that is one of the key points of Windows 11.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Thanks for the link.  Just a heads-up that you tagged Cameron in that comment, but it was actually me who asked that question :-)  Sad to hear that, but at least we can still use `xrdp` on individual distros with Windows 10/WSL.  I won't be able to update all my computers to Windows 11, that's for sure.

Comment: I am on the new WSL2 but it does not "just" work. I cannot open any GUIs.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop What version & build of Windows are you running? What is your `$DISPLAY` set to?

Comment: This answer is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412056). Please continue discussion about the appropriateness of the formatting in this answer on the meta post, instead of as comments on the answer.

Comment: October 2021 called to say that WSLg will be available in Win10's November 21H2 update (yes, build 22000+) and I just installed Win11 and using WSLg was easy peasy, so now as of date this solution works so it should not be downvoted. Although GWSL seems to work better since it's X-based, unlike WSLg which is Wayland-based, but it's good to have an official alternative :)

Comment: On Windows 11 I am now using WSLg.  This is the version information displayed:
wsl --version
WSL version: 0.50.2.0
Kernel version: 5.10.74.3
WSLg version: 1.0.29
Windows version: 10.0.22000.434

My PC no longer is enrolled in the Windows Preview program.

Comment: If you have issue, follow this guide to debug and diagnose. It works for me. 
https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/wiki/Diagnosing-%22cannot-open-display%22-type-issues-with-WSLg

Answer (score -4):

### 2022 update. simplest way, works without 3rd party apps

1. update your Windows to 22H2 or to W11, reboot
2. do wsl --update, reboot

---

original answer

This worked for WSL1, for WSL2 set appropriate IP adress

1. install xming server
2. on WSL run export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

[image]

Comment: This would not work with WSL2 which the author of this thread clearly uses (see title) because it uses a different subnet than WSL1.

Comment: For WSL2 use the following command, where 192.168.1.200 is my windows host ip export DISPLAY=192.168.1.200:0.0