# How to scrape data from an internal browser page such as "brave://rewards"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, brave-browser

##### Overview

My goal is to write a Bash script on WSL2 that pulls data from the Brave browser's home page and stores it in a text file. Specifically, I would like to access the value for 'Brave Rewards' seen in this picture and store it in a Bash variable:

[image: Screenshot of brave://rewards/]

[image: Screenshot of brave: No URL]

##### Issue

I can't figure out how to access this page programmatically.  There's no URL that I can use to download it with `wget` or `curl`. All I can find is `brave://rewards/`, which doesn't work from `curl` or `wget`:

```
# ISSUE GETTING CONTENTS
content=$(wget brave://rewards/ -q -O -)
echo $content
# Blank line returned
```

The browser is the Windows version, which I can launch either from the shell on WSL2/Ubuntu (via xlaunch) or directly from Windows.

Is there any way that I can programmatically access the "Brave Rewards" value or the `brave://rewards` URL?

Comment: That's not a URL, it's a browser-internal page, isn't it? Like chrome:// is in Chrome. If so, then you can't access it from anything but the Brave browser itself. You could try to automate from within, but even that will not be easy (if possible at all).

Comment: I believe in Brave the newtab page url is `chrome://newtab`

Comment: Very odd to me that this was closed as "needs details". It seemed perfectly clear what the question was asking to me.  That said, since I understood it and others apparently didn't feel it explained it well enough, I've provided an edited version for Reopen Votes.  It feels like a reasonable, if naive (and there's nothing wrong with that), question to me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't something you'll be able to "scrape", as you seem to be trying.  The `brave://rewards` page, as mentioned in the comments, is an *internal* browser page.  You won't have access to this page from `wget` or any other software, regardless of whether it is WSL, pure Linux, etc.

The browser apparently communicates with `api.rewards.brave.com` to get this information, but as far as I can tell there is no documentation on that API.

There might be two possibilities for obtaining the information you want programmatically:

- If you *really* want to "dig in", you *can* look at the source code (JavaScript and HTML) of `brave://rewards` from within the browser by starting the Developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).  The main script is `brave_rewards_page.bundle.js`.  It *may* be possible to reverse-engineer the script.
- Perhaps a better option, depending on how often you would want to do this, is to attempt to script this via [Python/Selenium/Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57837496/11810933).  Using this stack, you can "automate" the browser to open the `brave://rewards` page and access the contents of the `<div>` with the reward value.

  Some tips for doing this from WSL2:

  - You will need to use the Linux version of Brave.  Selenium on WSL2 won't be able to connect to the Windows Brave's chromedriver.
  - That means that you'll also need the ability to run GUI apps on WSL2.  This can be most easily done if you have the ability to upgrade to Windows 11 with WSLg support.  Alternatively, I prefer `xrdp` personally for accessing GUI apps in WSL2 on Windows 10.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63290844/11810933) and [a separate answer I provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856351/11810933) for more details.