# How do I specify the path to chrome.exe when configuring capybara for a rails project running in a WSL environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm developing my Rails application in a WSL environment on Windows 11.

I use VS Code for my editor, and use the WSL - Remote extension to connect to the WSL filesystem, edit my app, etc.

When I run `rake test:system` I get:

```
blaine@blaine_ems_dev:~/myapp$ rake test:system
rake aborted!
Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound: Failed to find Chrome binary.
/home/blaine/myapp/test/application_system_test_case.rb:7:in `<class:ApplicationSystemTestCase>'
/home/blaine/myapp/test/application_system_test_case.rb:3:in `<main>'
/home/blaine/myapp/test/system/customer_administration_stories_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:system
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Neat thing is, I can open Chrome via WSL by issuing this command:

`/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`

Is there some way I can simply plug in the path to the Windows binary I have installed, and have it run my system tests?

Or perhaps there's a better way altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can override webdrivers attempt to detect the location of Chrome by setting `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path` to the location of your Chrome binary or you can set the `WD_CHROME_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Under WSL, you are running the Linux version of Ruby, which won't be able to communicate via WebDriver with the Windows Chrome executable.

Similar to this [Python/Selenium/WSL2 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63290844/11810933), you'll need to install the Linux Chrome executable.

Since you have Windows 11, that shouldn't be a problem since it supports running GUI apps through WSLg.  I've successfully run Selenium using `xrdp` with Python on Windows 10, and I just ran `ruby2d` for another Ask Ubuntu question on Windows 11 using WSLg, so I'm fairly confident this will work for you.