# Connecting to Bloomberg API via XBBG on WSL2

Tags: wsl-2, bloomberg

Having difficulty connecting as default is localhost() for Bloomberg Comm and WSL2 doesn't get the localhost() being inside VM I saw there is a blp.connect that I can use and specify 192..xxxkind of IP but have not found any example. Anyone have done this? Thank you!

I did this but it just hangs

blp.connect(host=getOption("192.xx.xx..","localhost")
...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a localhost running in Windows from inside WSL2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763147/access-a-localhost-running-in-windows-from-inside-wsl2)

Comment: While I don't have access to Bloomberg, from a quick scan of the doc on how things work, it sounds like you are trying to connect a to Bloomberg Terminal in the *Windows* host in which WSL2 runs, is that right?  If so, I think the above question (and my answer there) should be able to provide what you need.  If not, please edit the question to provide more detail on your configuration.  Thanks!