# How can the app inside Docker container get data from SQL Server located on Window host

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

I have a problem to deploy my app for reading data located on Window host. Specifically, my situation is on the same machine:

1. The SQL Server installed and managed on Window host,
2. Docker app using engine of wsl2, I'm running a container on it
3. The app running inside the container cannot query data from the SQL Server on Window host.

So, how can I config them to run smoothly?

Comment: Please read this as this is a common question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/12790501

Comment: Have you tried `host.docker.internal` yet? Note that will only work in Docker Desktop, ref: [I want to connect from a container to a service on the host](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)