# Is there a way to connect to a Python API running over windows from wsl2?

Tags: python, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a fast API service running on windows, I need it there because it is connected to some native old services that only runs on windows right now. I have a node API running on docker-wsl. Is there any way I can do a post request to the windows API from WSL?

I've tried to connect using the IP instead of localhost but I think because of I'm running from docker it cannot connect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a localhost running in Windows from inside WSL 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763147/access-a-localhost-running-in-windows-from-inside-wsl-2)

Answer (score 1):

There's a special name you can use in the `add-host` option on your `docker run` command called `host-gateway`. That adds a hostname you can use to connect to services running on the docker host.

Usually the host name `host.docker.internal` is used, but you can use anything you want.

As an example, if your image is called `myimage`, you'd do something like

```
docker run --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -d myimage
```

If your API is running on port 1234, you'd then connect to it using hostname `host.docker.internal` and port `1234`.

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#add-host).

Answer (score 0):

In windows open a command line, in there type : `ipconfig`

There should be properties for an adapter called "vEthernet" (WSL).

This IPV4 is the address you should use instead of localhost from inside WSL, it usually starts with **172** (not sure if that's always the case though).

Comment: Should a `ping` on that address work from within WSL?  It doesn't for me.

Comment: Weird it works for me.

Comment: It works when I ping from Windows but not when I ping from WSL.  On the other hand pinging localhost from WSL works fine.

Comment: This did not work for the issue