# How can I get networking AND X11 forwarding in WSL 2 with Cisco Anyconnect?

Tags: cisco, wsl-2, x11-forwarding

So I can get X11 forwarding working in WSL2 following e.g., [How to set up working X11 forwarding on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2). Then I had issues getting networking to function after connecting to a Cisco AnyConnect server, but I solved that using, e.g., [WSL 2 Cisco AnyConnect Networking Workaround](https://gist.github.com/pyther/b7c03579a5ea55fe431561b502ec1ba8). This included manually setting up /etc/resolv.conf to include the DNS nameservers I need, although the DISPLAY variable for X11 should then be set via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63092879/10386269) to the X11 question.

But as soon as I connect to AnyConnect, I can no longer forward X11 apps, which even includes vim unless I add the `-X` argument (seemed odd, but what do I know). The apps don't show an error in display setting, they just don't show up. The same commands work fine as soon as I disconnect from the VPN. This happens regardless of the networking settings that need to happen, so I think it's only related to the AnyConnect itself, but perhaps there are additional Powershell commands I need to run so the display works? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same concern in my WSL2 environment. Once I opened a VPN connection via Cisco AnyConnect, the default network interface I had set within DISPLAY environment variable for X11 forwarding (which I retrieved from /etc/resolv.conf - same method as [the one you pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2)) wasn't accessible anymore.

I looked then for any Windows network interface ping-able from WSL2 side and with a 6000 port reachable (since this port seems to be the one used by default to establish X11 connections with X servers like VcXsrv). And by luck, I found the virtual network interface opened for the Windows host on the VPN, which matches these criteria:

```
Name                       : Ethernet 2
InterfaceDescription       : Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
InterfaceIndex             : 4
MacAddress                 : [...]
MediaType                  : 802.3
PhysicalMediaType          : Unspecified
InterfaceOperationalStatus : Up
AdminStatus                : Up
LinkSpeed(Mbps)            : 862.4
MediaConnectionState       : Connected
ConnectorPresent           : False
DriverInformation          : [...]
```

To be able to use it from WSL2 side, I used the following Powershell command to retrieve the interface's IP address:

```powershell
Get-NetAdapter |
  Where-Object InterfaceDescription -like "*AnyConnect*Virtual*Adapter*" | 
  Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
```

which can be wrapped into a Powershell call from WSL2, like following:

```bash
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command '<the_command_above>'
```

Once I got this IP address, I only had left to re-export my DISPLAY environment variable with it:

```bash
export DISPLAY="<vpn_ip_address>:0"
```

And that was it, I could enjoy X11 forwarding back again!

Comment: this does not work for me unfortunately.