# WSL Ubuntu showing "Error: Unable to open display" even after manually setting display environment variable

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glfw

I'm using g++ on WSL Ubuntu. I cloned the GLFW repo using git, used the `ccmake` command to configure and generate the binaries, then used `make` inside the "build" directory to finally create the `.a` file. I installed all the OpenGL-related libraries to `/usr/ld` (I don't recall exactly which I installed, since I had to install so many. Regardless, the g++ command works, so I assume it was a success). Afterwards, I made a project on VS Code that looks like this:

[image]

The GLFW include-folder is from the aforementioned cloned repo, and the GLAD and KHR include-folders are from [glad.dav1d.de](http://glad.dav1d.de), where I set the GL version (under API) to *3.3*, and the Profile to *Core*.

In `main.cpp`, I put a simple snippet of code meant to initialize GLFW:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then used this to command to compile the project: `g++ -Wall -I./include/ -L./lib/ src/*.{c,cpp} -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi -ldl -o main`. There were no warnings or errors or anything. After running the executable, I get the error message that GLFW failed to initialize. I was a little confused why this happened, so I typed the `glxinfo` command to find out that my `DISPLAY` environment variable hasn't been set.

I have absolutely no idea what this variable is, or what it's meant to represent. After scouring around on the internet, I came across `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and `export DISPLAY=1` and `export DISPLAY=IP:0.0`, none of which worked. Any ideas on how I could resolve this?

Comment: `DISPLAY` indicates where the X display server is running. Instead of googling around for what `DISPLAY` server is set to, try Googling around for what it means and how it works, and maybe it'll point to a clue. Perhaps you're using a Wayland-only server without X display server support.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, you're right. Apologies for not digging into this deeper. After looking around for explanations, I now have a better understanding of what it actually is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WSL on Windows 10 does not include support for GUI apps.  You can build an app with OpenGL/X libraries, sure, but running it requires an X server on which to actually display it.

In general, you have 3 options.  I believe all of these will work with OpenGL, although I have not tested each of them in that capacity:

- The "supported" method is to use Windows 11 with WSLg.  Windows 11 supports hardware-accelerated OpenGL in WSL2 out-of-the-box using a supported WDDMv3.0 driver (available for AMD, Intel, and nVidia GPUs). See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) for more information.
- The "normal" method of running an X server on WSL with Windows 10 is to install a third-party X server such as VcXsrv.  See [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1487555/1210833) for some details on OpenGL support under that scenario.  I don't believe that this will be hardware-accelerated, however.

  You'll need to manually configure the `DISPLAY` variable in this case to point to your Windows host.  You'll find some fairly [complicated directions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61860208/11810933) for doing so, but IMHO the easiest way is via [mDNS](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/rdzjic/psa_stop_using_complicated_display_pipelines/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).
- Before upgrading to Windows 11, I used xrdp when I needed X support.  This allows access to the WSL instance using the Remote Desktop Protocol and supported apps like the built-in Windows Remote Desktop Connection.  I don't believe there is a way to hardware accelerate OpenGL using RDP, either.  In my opinion, this is far easier than setting up a 3rd party X server.  See my [answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986) for steps to enable.

Comment: Thank you! I went with the second method (and also followed this guide: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242) and so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

WSL 2 now has support for GUI apps on Windows 11:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

I had just installed the GPU driver, updated WSL, and now it works for me.

Comment: Wait, so is it possible to run your own OpenGL C++ applications using WSL now?

Comment: @Diego - Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'd encourage you to read the existing answers to questions before posting duplicate information.  I already covered that Windows 11 WSL2 includes this capability in my previous answer.  Also, your answer doesn't point out that it won't work on Windows 10.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds It was probably an accident. I restored the accept now. Continue on with your day.

Comment: This essentially just repeats the existing answer.

Comment: Thanks @RapidReaders - I have no problem with better answers coming along and displacing mine, but I was confused on this one since this (IMHO) wasn't a better answer.  Happy to hear it wasn't intentional, and thanks for fixing it!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, sorry... I tried to find for an answer for days, and some day I could get it working by installing a program on windows and a lot of things in wsl, but when i formatted my pc, it didn't work anymore. When I found this driver on Microsoft docs, I tried just to help others and I just saw that you said that there is no support. I'll take more attention next time. I was just trying to help looking for questions with this problem.