# Electron not starting properly due to SIGTRAP

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, windows-subsystem-for-linux, desktop-application

I am getting into Electron to try to begin building desktop applications. I am running into this error:

```
/home/me/dev/my-electron-app-2/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
```

This path leads to a binary file, so I can't really read what is happening. This error comes when I run:

```
npm start
```

My goal is to have a window appear on my desktop reflecting the HTML page. So far, the app is just:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    })
  
    win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
  })
```

This code has come from the docs, here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start

I have googled quite a bit and have been unable to find a solution that sticks. I am using Ubuntu in WSL. If anyone has any advice it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe related? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/31885

Answer (score 0):

Since electron is a GUI application, and you are using Ubuntu on WSL (I'm assuming WSL2?), you need to run an X server for Ubuntu have something to render the GUI on.

You can download and install VcXsrv from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

How to configure it is explained in the top answer to this question: [How to set up working X11 forwarding on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2)

Your other option is to not use WSL; just run node, npm and electron directly on your Windows machine. Then, you will not need to install any separate X server; your app should just work.

Answer (score 0):

My issue causing this error was just that I needed to change the "main" entry in package.json:

`"main": "main.js",`