# Cannot open display in WSL 2, py-qt5

Tags: opencv, keras, wsl-2

How to display the application in windows.
[image: Python keras + Opencv +]

Code for Reference:

```
from tkinter import N
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import cv2
import imutils
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

# parameters for loading data and images
detection_model_path = 'ER_Project//haar-cascade-files-master/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
emotion_model_path = 'ER_Project/_mini_XCEPTION.102-0.66.hdf5'

# hyper-parameters for bounding boxes shape
# loading models
face_detection = cv2.CascadeClassifier(detection_model_path)
emotion_classifier = load_model(emotion_model_path, compile=False)
EMOTIONS = ["angry", "disgust", "scared", "happy", "sad", "surprised",
            "neutral"]


#feelings_faces = []
# for index, emotion in enumerate(EMOTIONS):
# feelings_faces.append(cv2.imread('emojis/' + emotion + '.png', -1))

# starting video streaming
cv2.namedWindow('your_face')
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    print("Hello")
    frame = camera.read()[1]
    # reading the frame
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=300)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detection.detectMultiScale(
        gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    canvas = np.zeros((250, 300, 3), dtype="uint8")
    frameClone = frame.copy()
    if len(faces) > 0:
        faces = sorted(faces, reverse=True,
                       key=lambda x: (x[2] - x[0]) * (x[3] - x[1]))[0]
        (fX, fY, fW, fH) = faces
        # Extract the ROI of the face from the grayscale image, resize it to a fixed 28x28 pixels, and then prepare
        # the ROI for classification via the CNN
        roi = gray[fY:fY + fH, fX:fX + fW]
        roi = cv2.resize(roi, (64, 64))
        roi = roi.astype("float") / 255.0
        roi = img_to_array(roi)
        roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)

        preds = emotion_classifier.predict(roi)[0]
        emotion_probability = np.max(preds)
        label = EMOTIONS[preds.argmax()]
    else:
        continue

    for (i, (emotion, prob)) in enumerate(zip(EMOTIONS, preds)):
        # construct the label text
        text = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(emotion, prob * 100)

        # draw the label + probability bar on the canvas
       # emoji_face = feelings_faces[np.argmax(preds)]

        w = int(prob * 300)
        cv2.rectangle(canvas, (7, (i * 35) + 5),
                      (w, (i * 35) + 35), (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(canvas, text, (10, (i * 35) + 23),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,
                    (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frameClone, label, (fX, fY - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frameClone, (fX, fY), (fX + fW, fY + fH),
                      (0, 0, 255), 2)
#    for c in range(0, 3):
#        frame[200:320, 10:130, c] = emoji_face[:, :, c] * \
#        (emoji_face[:, :, 3] / 255.0) + frame[200:320,
#        10:130, c] * (1.0 - emoji_face[:, :, 3] / 255.0)

    cv2.imshow('your_face', frameClone)
    cv2.imshow("Probabilities", canvas)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
NUMA SUPPORT:
2022-04-20 04:36:21.181568: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:922] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-04-20 04:36:21.181664: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3951 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
```

> I need to run this openCV gui app on windows.

Comment: Were you able to run other graphical applications before? Did you already try to use X server to display graphical interfaces and fail? Otherwise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2/61110604#61110604) should help.

Comment: yes, Xlaunch is working and i am able to open the app in the Xlaunch. But can i able to open it in windows like VSCode ?